# Issue working with ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar while using Salesforce ANT Migration Tool

Tags: ant, salesforce

I believe I set everything up correctly, but I'm getting the following errors when running my Powershell script that calls the ANT Migration executable:

```
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\backup_script.ps1:13 char:1
+ &ant "retrieveObjects"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   BUILD FAILED C:\Users\user\Desktop\AntCode\ant-salesforce-prgm\build.xml:63: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:com.salesforce:retrieve Cause: The name is undefined. Action: Check the spelling. Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared. Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place. No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet This appears to be an antlib declaration.  Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -C:\apache-ant-1.10.2\lib
        -C:\Users\user\.ant\lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument Total time: 0 seconds
```

Here is my build.xml file:

```
<project name="Sample usage of Salesforce Ant tasks" default="test" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property environment="env"/>

    <!-- Setting default value for username, password and session id properties to empty string 
         so unset values are treated as empty. Without this, ant expressions such as ${sf.username}
         will be treated literally.
    -->
    <macrodef name="export">
        <attribute name="file"/>
        <attribute name="object"/>
        <attribute name="soql"/>
        <attribute name="userName"/>
        <attribute name="password"/>
        <attribute name="serverURL"/>
        <attribute name="batchSize"/>
        <attribute name="limit"/> 

        <sequential>
            <echo message="Exporting @{object}"/>
            <mkdir dir="exports/DATE"/>
            <mkdir dir="logs/DATE"/>
            <copy file="config/template-process-conf.xml" tofile="config/process-conf.xml" overwrite="true" failonerror="true"/>
            <replace file="config/process-conf.xml">
                <replacefilter token="_object_" value="@{object}"/>
                <replacefilter token="_soql_" value="@{soql}"/>
                <replacefilter token="_file_" value="exports/${todayDate_only}/@{file}.csv"/>
                <replacefilter token="_serverURL_" value="@{serverURL}"/>
                <replacefilter token="_userName_" value="@{username}"/>
                <replacefilter token="_password_" value="@{password}"/>
                <replacefilter token="_batchSize_" value="@{batchSize}"/>
                <replacefilter token="_logFile_" value="logs/DATE/@{file}_log.csv"/>
            </replace>
            <java classname="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner" classpath="C:\YOUR_PATH\dataloader-39.0.0-uber.jar" failonerror="true">
                <sysproperty key="salesforce.config.dir" value="config"/>
                <arg line="process.name=@{object}"/>
            </java>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <!--
    <condition property="sf.username" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.username"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.password" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.password"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.sessionId" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.sessionId"/> </not> </condition>

    <taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:com.salesforce">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="ant-salesforce.jar" />           
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    -->

    <!-- See what happens here -->
    <target name="retrieveObjects">
      <mkdir dir="retrieveObjects"/>
      <sf:retrieve 
          username="${sf.prod.profileName.username}" 
          password="${sf.prod.profileName.password}" 
          sessionId="${sfProd.sessionId}"
          serverurl="${sfProd.serverurl}" 
          retrieveTarget="retrieveObjects" 
          unpackaged="retrieveSource/package.xml"/>
    </target>

        <target name="foo">
        <foreach target="backup" param="file">  
            <path>
                <fileset dir="YOUR_PATH_objects" includes="**/*.object"/>
            </path>
        </foreach>
    </target>

    <target name="backup">
        <xmlproperty file="retrieveObjects/objects/Account.object" collapseAttributes="true"/> <!--this parses the xml file-->

        <export
            file="Account_backup-DATE"
            object="Account"
            soql="select ${CustomObject.fields.fullName} from Account"
            userName="${sf.prod.profileName.username}"
            password="${sf.prod.profileName.password}"
            serverURL="${sfProd.serverurl}"
            batchSize="200"
            limit = "1000" />
    </target>

</project>
```

I'm not sure where the issue is occurring. I dropped the ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar file into the following directory: **C:\apache-ant-1.10.2\lib** but that didn't seem to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your ant-version.
It is possible that your ant-contrib file is not compatible with the version of ant that you are running.

I had a similar error and it was resolved by using the ant-contrib-1.0b1.jar instead. Download [ant-contrib-1.0b1-bin.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/ant-contrib-1.0b1/) and extract it to find the .jar file inside it.

The version of ant I'm running is 1.10.3

Also you could try adding this to your build.xml file:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Had no effect Chandrani. Still the same problem. I'm running v1.10.2. Some guy wiped his ANT install and redid it to get things to work. Would that help?